# Best Approach to compare two dates in java

Tags: java, performance

what is the best approach to compare two dates in java?

i need to set date, month and year for both the dates and i should compare those both dates

I am using Calendar object to set the values

```
Calendar calendar1 = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar1.set(Calendar.YEAR, 2015);
calendar1.set(Calendar.MONTH, 5);
calendar1.set(Calendar.DATE, 17);

Calendar calendar2 = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar2.set(Calendar.YEAR, 2015);
calendar2.set(Calendar.MONTH, 5);
calendar2.set(Calendar.DATE, 18);

    if (calendar1.compareTo(calendar2) < 0) {
        // if calendar1 is less than calendar2
    }
```

I handling lot of comparisons throughout my application.

For Performance, Using java.util.Calendar is the right approach?

Comment: Note: Months are **zero**-based in class `Calendar`. Month 5 is June, not May. Also, integer literals that start with a `0` like `05` are interpreted as [octal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Octal) numbers. Use `calendar1.set(Calendar.MONTH, Calendar.MAY);` instead of `calendar1.set(Calendar.MONTH, 05);`.

Comment: Not sure hence the comment, but you could create 2 instance of the Calendar class once, and then simply update the time of each for each comparison.

Comment: @Martin note that 5 means **June** not May - use the constants in class `Calendar` instead of numbers for the months.

Comment: Are you going to compare a lot of dates?

Comment: You can use before and after methods, they are a bit more readable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's probably better to use Java 8's LocalDate, since Calendar also represents time. In your example, calendar1 and calendar2 would have slightly different times, since you let them default.

If you are using an earlier version of Java, you can use the Joda date library instead.

Finally, if you don't have an actual performance problem, don't worry about it.  If you do have a performance problem that you know is attributable to date comparisons (because you profiled the code), try different ways of doing the comparison, and benchmark them to find out what is most performant.

Comment: Aren't the `Calendar`s,... translated into a `long` storing the number of ticks? In that case one only needs to do a `long`-comparison which is rather cheap I think...

Comment: They are stored as long values (milliseconds since the epoch), but they're difficult to deal with because they include a Time component, which is not necessary in this situation. Depending on how they are initialized, they may have different time values, when all the OP cares about is date. If performance is a huge problem, then careful initialization, along with comparison of the longs might be a good solution. But again, you'd have to profile to be sure.